# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_type' in snake game

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Can't change food into food images

I am almost done with my snake game but the problem occurs when I turn the food into real food and not just circles.

food.py:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from random import randint, choice
from foods import foods, shape_names


class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape(choice(shape_names))
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stretch_wid=0.5)
        self.color('blue')
        self.speed(0)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        rand_x = randint(-280, 280)
        rand_y = randint(-280, 280)
        self.shape(choice(shape_names))
        self.goto(x=rand_x, y=rand_y)
```

foods.py:

```
apple = 'food/apple.png'
burger = 'food/burger.png'
cake = 'food/cake.png'
cherries = 'food/cherries.png'
donut = 'food/donut.png'
drumstick = 'food/drumstick.png'
icecream = 'food/icecream.png'
lemon = 'food/lemon.png'
meat = 'food/meat.png'
pizza = 'food/pizza.png'
strawberry = 'food/strawberry.png'
taco = 'food/taco.png'

foods = {'apple': apple, 'burger': burger, 'cake': cake, 'cherries': cherries, 'donut': donut, 'drumstick': drumstick,
         'icecream': icecream, 'lemon': lemon, 'meat': meat, 'pizza': pizza, 'strawberry': strawberry, 'taco': taco}

shape_names = ['apple', 'burger', 'cake', 'cherries', 'donut', 'drumstick', 'icecream', 'lemon', 'meat', 'pizza',
               'strawberry', 'taco']
```

This is what I got :( :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ZSH\PycharmProjects\snake-game\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    food = Food()
  File "C:\Users\ZSH\PycharmProjects\snake-game\food.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.shape('meat')
  File "C:\Users\ZSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 2778, in shape
    self.turtle._setshape(name)
  File "C:\Users\ZSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 2494, in _setshape
    if self._type == "polygon" == screen._shapes[shapeIndex]._type:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_type'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I dont get the fact that I want the apple.png and meat.png and whatnot, and python thinks its just a mere string??? How can I solve this?

Comment: -PLEASE dont get confused between food.py and foods.py-

Comment: This is not a [mre]. The code with `self.shape('meat')` is not present in your example code. It's just in your error. That said, it doesn't appear that you are registering the new shapes anywhere, like [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape) says to do. Please read the documentation about how `shape()` works and then see if you still have questions.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `.png` format?

Comment: Maybe; they only have an example with a `.gif` so maybe you have to use that. But regardless it seems that you're not using the library properly. For example, you have to register shapes first via `screen.register_shape(meat)`, where the value of `meat` is `food/meat.png`. It appears, according to the documentation, that this is what causes the code to actually treat that string as a path, and register the name `food/meat.png` as a useable shape. But maybe you have to use a `.gif` instead. You just have to play around with it and see what happens.